# Laravel Eloquent has many through variation, remove duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, eloquent-relationship

I've been trying to get a variation of the Laravel Eloquent 'has many through' relation working.

I have 3 models: Invoice, InvoiceLine and Order; I would like to retrieve a distinct set of all Orders of a given Invoice through its InvoiceLines.

Invoice has 1 or more InvoiceLines; InvoiceLine has exactly 1 Invoice; InvoiceLine has zero or 1 Order; Order has zero or more InvoiceLines

Below is a simplified version of the tables:

- Invoice

  - id
- InvoiceLine

  - invoice_id
  - orderid
- Order

  - orderid

First I thought to use the default [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship but that won't work because my tables are different:

Then I thought to use the Many-To-Many (`belongsToMany`) relation:

```php
class Invoice {
    public function orders(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Order::class,
            'invoice_line',
            'invoice_id',
            'orderid'
        );
    }
}
```

The above code works for getting all orders, but the list is full of duplicates.

How can I setup this `Invoice --> Order` relation using Laravel 5.6 Eloquent ORM but have it so that the collection of Orders does not have any duplicates?

If this is not possible in a Eloquent ORM relationship definition, then how can I query these models in a different way so that I still have a relational object oriented collection of Invoices with its distinct set of related Orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this can be done in Eloquent builder. Maybe something like this:

```
public function orders(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Order::class,
        'invoice_line',
        'invoice_id',
        'orderid'
    )->distinct();
}
```

But you can also do:

```
// class Invoice
public function getRelatedOrders ()
{
    $orderIdList = $this->invoiceLines->pluck('order_id')->unique();
    return Order::whereIn('id', $orderIdList)->get();
{
```

Comment: @Dediqated did `->distinct()` work?

Comment: Yeah it does work!